# How to change values in XML file

Tags: xml

I have an `XML` file like below. I want change the values at `is-required` place and `default-value` place of each argument name using a shell script..

- where `argument name=protocol` then `is-required = "true"` and `default-value=tcp`,
- where `argument name =port` then `is-required = "true"` `default-value= 7223`,
- where `argument name =`then and `is-required = "true"` `default-value=test`,

Example:

```
<task-arguments>
    <argument name="protocol" is-required="false" default-value="ssl"/>
    <argument name="port" is-required="true" default-value="7222"/>
    <argument name="username" is-required="true" default-value="admin"/>
</task-arguments>
```

Comment: You can use the python xml library

Answer (score 7):

Using [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```bash
xml ed -P \
    -u '//argument[@name="protocol"]/@is-required' -v true \
    -u '//argument[@name="protocol"]/@default-value' -v tcp \
    -u '//argument[@name="port"]/@is-required' -v true \
    -u '//argument[@name="port"]/@default-value' -v 7223 \
    -u '//argument[@name="username"]/@is-required' -v true \
    -u '//argument[@name="username"]/@default-value' -v admin \
        file.xml
```

Result for your sample:

```xml
<task-arguments>
    <argument name="protocol" is-required="true" default-value="tcp"/>
    <argument name="port" is-required="true" default-value="7223"/>
    <argument name="username" is-required="true" default-value="admin"/>
</task-arguments>
```